# How do I get from "Big Data" to a webpage?

Tags: hadoop, rdbms, bigdata, nosql

I've spent a lot of time reading and watching videos of people talking about how they use tools designed for handling huge datasets and real-time processing in their architectures. And while I understand what it is that tools like Hadoop/Cassandra/Kafka etc do, no one seems to explain how the data gets from these large processing tools to rendering something on a client/webpage.

From what I understand of big data tools, is that you can't build your application the same way you would a standard web-app querying MySQL, which I can understand given the size of the data that flows through these tools, however, for all this talk of "realtime data analytics" I cannot find any explanation of how the actual analytics gets put in front of someone in terms of some chart/table/etc?

Answer (score 0):

> explain how the data gets from these large processing tools to rendering something on a client/webpage.

With respect to this, one way would be to process the big data using Spark or Hadoop and store the results onto a RDBMS. Then have your webapp pull data from RDBMS to render charts, table etc. I can provide you the examples that I have done myself if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Impala** supports ODBC/JDBC interfaces. So, you actually could hook up a web app to it the same way you do with MySQL.

Other stuff you might want to check out is **HBase**, **Kudu** or **Solr**. In some realtime architectures data ends up in one of those. And all of them have some sort of an API that you can use in your web app to access their data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple solution for realtime data processing and analytics, check out the new [Stride API](http://www.stride.io), which enables developers to collect, process, and analyze streaming data and then either visualize summary data in Stride or push processed data out to applications in realtime. This is a very easy way to build the kind of realtime reporting dashboards and monitoring / alerting systems you described above.

Take a look at the Stride API [technical docs](http://www.stride.io/docs) for examples and more info on how to implement this.